# Pandas Dataframe reorganizing columns and rows

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to consolidate channel lists from providers to show all channels as the row indices and values as the provider name.  Currently organized as:

```
         DIRECTV           FUBO     YOUTUBE TV
0            A&E            A&E            ABC
1            ABC     ADULT SWIM            AMC
2    ACCUWEATHER            AMC  ANIMAL PLANET
3            AMC  ANIMAL PLANET            BBC
4  ANIMAL PLANET            BBC      BBC WORLD
```

I would like the result to be (header row can be anything):

```
A&E            DIRECTV  FUBO
ABC            DIRECTV        YOUTUBE TV
ACCUWEATHER    DIRECTV
ADULT SWIM              FUBO
AMC            DIRECTV  FUBO  YOUTUBE TV
ANIMAL PLANET  DIRECTV  FUBO  YOUTUBE TV
BBC                     FUBO  YOUTUBE TV
BBC WORLD                     YOUTUBE TV
```

I believe this should be accomplished very simply through a join, merge, or other, but I can't get it working.  Any help would be appreciated.

Note: the above images are obviously just a small sample of the list, the index column should be every unique channel from all providers.  Something along the lines of "df.values.unique()".  Yes, I know that doesn't work.

Comment: Please post frames as text, not images

Comment: There's no point in having the word repeated in every cell. More naturally, you'd have the Provider as the column header than 1 and 0 indicating presence or absence. (this is a typical dummy problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, this is a `melt` + `crosstab` problem

---

```
u = df.melt(
    var_name='provider',
    value_name='channel'
)

pd.crosstab(
  index=u['channel'],
  columns=u['provider'],
  values=u['provider'],
  aggfunc='first'
)
```

```
provider       DIRECTV  FUBO  YOUTUBE TV
channel
A&E            DIRECTV  FUBO         NaN
ABC            DIRECTV   NaN  YOUTUBE TV
ACCUWEATHER    DIRECTV   NaN         NaN
ADULT SWIM         NaN  FUBO         NaN
AMC            DIRECTV  FUBO  YOUTUBE TV
ANIMAL PLANET  DIRECTV  FUBO  YOUTUBE TV
BBC                NaN  FUBO  YOUTUBE TV
BBC WORLD          NaN   NaN  YOUTUBE TV
```

---

If you would rather a simple `1` or `0` if a value exists, just omit the `aggfunc` and `values` argument from crosstab:

```
pd.crosstab(u['channel'], u['provider'])
```

```
provider       DIRECTV  FUBO  YOUTUBE TV
channel
A&E                  1     1           0
ABC                  1     0           1
ACCUWEATHER          1     0           0
ADULT SWIM           0     1           0
AMC                  1     1           1
ANIMAL PLANET        1     1           1
BBC                  0     1           1
BBC WORLD            0     0           1
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  I don't understand it, but will work to learn.  melt + crosstab.